How to un-stuck 'Testing..' in watchOS Unit testing?
I added a unit test target for my watchOS schema today and it showed strange behaviour. A) a previously spawned watchOS simulator (for running the watchOS schema) was just vanishing whenever I started the unit test suite (via CMD+U) and b) it stuck in "Testing...' forever.

The answer to solving the issue was to uncheck 'Execute in parallel' in the watchOS schema under Test > Test Plans > Test Plan Arrow.
